# postgresql: Accidentally deleted pg_filenode.map

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to recover or re-create pg_filenode.map file that was accidentally deleted? Or is there any solution on how to fix this issue without affecting the database?  Any suggestions to fix this issue is highly appreciated! The postgres version that we have is 9.0 running in Redhat Linux 5.  Thanks!

Comment: Restore your latest backup...

Comment: You're running Red Hat 2.6?  That is ancient!

Comment: sorry, its Redhat Version 5 (2.6.18-194.el5xen)

Comment: The problem is we dont have a backup :(

Comment: Then apparently your data wasn't really that important.

Answer (score 2):

**STOP TRYING TO FIX ANYTHING RIGHT NOW**. Everything you do risks making it worse.

Treat this as critical database corruption. [Read and act on this wiki article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).

Only once you have followed its advice should you even consider attempting repair or recovery.

Since you may have some hope of recovering the deleted file if it hasn't been overwritten yet, you should also STOP THE ENTIRE SERVER MACHINE or unmount the file system PostgreSQL is on and disk image it.

If this data is important to you I advise you to contact professional support. This will cost you, but is probably your best chance of getting your data back after a severe administrator mistake like this. See [PostgreSQL professional support](http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/). (Disclaimer: I work for one of the listed companies as shown in my SO profile).

It's possible you could reconstruct `pg_filenode.map` by hand using information about the table  structure and contents extracted from the on-disk tables. Probably a big job, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, if this is urgent and valuable, I strongly recommend contacting professional support initially.  However, if you can work on a disk image, if it is not time critical, etc. here are important points to note and how to proceed (we recently had to recover a bad pg_filenode.map.  Moreover you are better off working on a disk image of a disk image.

What follows is what I learned from having to recover a damaged file due to an incomplete write on the containing directory.  **It is current to PostgreSQL 10, but that could change at any time**

**Before you begin**

Data recovery is risky business.  Always note what recovery means to your organization, what data loss is tolerable, what downtime is tolerable etc before you begin.  Work on a copy of a copy if you can.  If anything doesn't seem right, circle back, evaluate what went wrong and make sure you understand why before proceeding.

**What this file is and what it does**

The standard file node map for PostgreSQL is stored in the pg_class relation which is referenced by object id inside the Pg catalogs.  Unfortunately you need a way to bootstrap the mappings of the system tables so you can look up this sort of informatuion.

In most deployments this file will never be written.  It can be copied from a new initdb on the same version of Postgres with the same options passed to initdb aside from data directory.  However this is not guaranteed.

Several things can change this mapping.  If you do a vacuum full or similar on system catalogs, this can change the mapping from the default and then copying in a fresh file from an initdb will not help.

**Some Things to Try**

The first thing to try (on a copy of a copy!) is to replace the file with one from a fresh initdb onto another filesystem from the same server (this could be a thumb drive or whatever).  This may work.  It may not work.

If that fails, then it would be possible perhaps to use pg_filedump and custom scripting/C programming to create a new file based on efforts to look through the data of each relation file in the data directory.  This would be significant work as Craig notes above.

**If you get it to work**

Take a fresh pg_dump of your database and restore it into a fresh initdb.  This way you know everything is consistent and complete.